# Imagebuttons won't align on the right next to eachother

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-imagebutton

I'm dynamically injecting rows in a container of a fragment.
But I just can't seem to get the three image buttons aligned to the right, next to each other.

Anyone an idea?

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scenesScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/switchLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scenesTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/switch_title"
            android:text="@string/title_switches" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/switch_row_name"
        android:text="Switch name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_lastSeen"
        android:layout_below="@id/switch_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/switch_row_lastSeen"
        android:text="@string/last_seen"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_status"
        android:layout_below="@id/switch_lastSeen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/switch_row_level"
        android:text="@string/status"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_button_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_button_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stop"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch_button_down"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/switch_button_down"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_button_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch_button_up"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/switch_button_up"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How the row looks on my phone (the same on a API 19 AVD):
[image: Borked images]

How Android Studio, when designing, shows the row:
[image: Layout as in the designer]

Comment: try getting rid of the  android:layout_toStartOf. you could also but those three buttons inside another horizontal linear layout and have that align right. But on another note, anything with rows should be using a ListView you should not be injecting rows in manually

Comment: Thanks, adding a LinearLayout inside the row did the trick. Already tried without layout_toStartOf but that's what the GUI of Android Studio did in my 15th attempt to resolve the issue. Will also look into a custom ListView adapter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switch_name"
    style="@style/switch_row_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Switch name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switch_lastSeen"
    style="@style/switch_row_lastSeen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/switch_name"
    android:text="@string/last_seen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switch_status"
    style="@style/switch_row_level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/switch_lastSeen"
    android:text="@string/status" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_button_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_button_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stop" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_button_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Coincidentally did this as per your previous comment and that did the trick! Thanks!